# Script to find x265 files then output name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, for

I'm trying to make a script that crawls through a giving directory and list all files that are x265. Using mediainfo and can see if the file is x264 or x265, I then use sed to clean up the text. The part that is eluding me is:

1.How do i phrase a command that works in cli but not here and
2.How do i get it to include subdirectories.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ls
search='mediainfo $file | grep -E "Writing library"| sed 's/.*x//'| sed 's/\s.*$//''
 if [ $search -eq 265 ] 
 then 
  echo $file is a 265 
 else 
  echo $file is not 265 and is $search 
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use format of `for` like this:

```
for file in **/*
```

to get all files in current and subdirectories.

To assign return value to variable use backticks

```
search=`mediainfo $file | grep -E "Writing library"| sed 's/.*x//'| sed 's/\s.*$//'`
```

If you use something like you may simplify your output:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Codec%" $file
```

or

```
ffprobe $file 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Stream.*Video
```